# Found bits not assigned (vivado)

Tags: verilog, xilinx, vivado

I have an **ASSIGN-9** linting violation in Vivado, and would like to get rid of it.

I have a complex module that has this error, but I was able to write a simple reproducible example that shows it well enough:

```
`timescale 1ps / 1ps

module test1 (
    input clk,
    input prev,
    output reg next
); 
    always @(posedge clk ) begin
        next <= prev;
    end
endmodule

module test2 #(
    parameter param = 3
) (
    input clk,
    input first
);
    wire [0:param - 2] link;

    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 0; i < param; i = i + 1) begin : test1_
            test1 t1
            (
                .clk(clk),
                .prev(i ? link[i-1] : first)
            );
            // The last one is not linked to anything
            if (i < param - 1) begin
                assign link[i] = t1.next;
            end
        end       
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

The problem of course comes from the fact that the last **test1** has the **next** output port that is not connected to anything. I actually want it to stay that way, and do not need that connection. How can I tell Vivado about this in a cleanest way?

I have tried `(* keep="soft" *)`, but it does not work

P.S.
The code works as intended, I do not have an issue with it. It's just the linter violation that I would like to get rid of.

Comment: You declared the signal `first` as an input. You shouldn't drive it.

Comment: I am not driving it, its the next that I ma interested in. I am not sure what make you think that I am driving first?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I never saw module ports assigned as you did with `assign link[i] = t1.next;`. I am not sure it is correct.

Comment: Maybe define the signal `link` as `wire [0:param - 1] link;`. Assign it to the `next` port of `t1` in the component initialization as `.next(link[i])`. And leave `link[param-1]` unassigned.

Comment: If you do not connect 'next', why do you declare it as an output port? Have you tried to have it just as an internal variable in test1?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `next` to not be connected to anything, then use `.next()` in the port connection to tell the simulator/synthesizer/linter/etc that the empty connection is intentional. That should resolve the warning.

```
            test1 t1
            (
                .clk(clk),
                .prev(i ? link[i-1] : first),
                .next() // <- connect to nothing
            );
```

---

That said, be aware that probing signals via module hierarchically is intended for verfication an other non-synthesizable coding. A synthesizable RTL design should connect signals through the port interface only. The optimzation stage will remove any unused logic during synthesis, so there is little reason to not connect `next` to a net.

You probably want to do something like this for cleaner code:

```
module test2 #(
    parameter param = 3
) (
    input clk,
    input first,
    output out
);
    wire [0:param] link;

    assign link[0] = first;
    assign out = link[param]; // out=first if param==0
    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 1; i <= param; i = i + 1) begin : test1_ // Note 'i' starts at 1,
            test1 t1
            (
                .clk(clk),
                .prev(link[i-1]),
                .next(link[i])
            );
        end       
    endgenerate
endmodule
```